# Appveyor test for monorepo where parts of the project use different NodeJS versions

Tags: node.js, appveyor

I am working on a mono-repo project that has this simplified structure:

- js_app_1
- js_app_2
- python_apps

First `js_app_1` can use NodeJS up to a v10, because of outdated plugins, but the `js_app_2` is completely new, with bleeding edge plugins. At this moment, we are limited by the Appveyor in testing everything on NodeJS v10, but I would like to make a configuration where `js_app_1` will be tested only with nodeJS v10 and `js_app_2` with always the latest one.

Is there a way to achieve this in Appveyor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch between Node versions with `Install-Product node [version] [bitness]` PowerShell command, for example `Install-Product node 10` for the latest 10.x and `Install-Product node ''` for the always latest one (currently 14.x).

You can either build/test both JS apps sequentially in a single build job, i.e. "cd into js_app_1, switch Node version, build/test then cd into js_app_2, switch Node version, build/test" or configure multi-job "matrix" build for each JS app and python apps: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-matrix